# Pandas groupby with conditional filtering based on quantity of values in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So say I have a table like...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Part Number" : [123456, 123456, 123456, 123456, 987654, 987654, 987654, 987654, 654321, 654321, 654321, 654321],
    "Operation" : [000, 100, 200, 300, 000, 100, 200, 300, 000, 100, 200, 300],
    "Source" : ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
})
```

Is there a way to use `df.groupby().filter()` to intelligently remove the row *987654 100 B* where the removal condition is `if (df["Source"]=="A").count() > 0` then remove B, else, do nothing.

I did something similar to this earlier where I got rid of every part number that didn't have a 000 operation by using `df = df.groupby("Part Number").filter(lambda x: (x["Operation"] == "000").any())` but the filter with count isn't working as intended, as the line of code I've been playing with doesn't do what's intended and I'd really not like to use a for loop for this:

`df = df.groupby("Part Number").filter(lambda x: (x["Source"] == "A").count() > 0)`

Again, the final result should intelligently remove the row *987654 100 B* where the removal condition is `if (df["Source"]=="A").count() > 0` then remove B or multiple instances of B, else, do nothing. Basically as long as there is an A, remove all Bs.

Expected output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Part Number" : [123456, 123456, 123456, 123456, 987654, 987654, 987654, 654321, 654321, 654321, 654321],
    "Operation" : [000, 100, 200, 300, 000, 200, 300, 000, 100, 200, 300],
    "Source" : ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
})
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# is there more than one A per Source?
m1 = df['Source'].eq('A').groupby(df['Part Number']).transform('sum').gt(1)
# alternative
m1 = df['Source'].eq('A').groupby(df['Part Number']).transform('any')

# is the row a B?
m2 = df['Source'].eq('B')

# is the group 987654?
m3 = df['Part Number'].eq(987654)

# drop the rows that match all conditions
out = df[~(m1 & m2 & m3)]
```

Output:

```
    Part Number  Operation Source
0        123456          0      A
1        123456        100      A
2        123456        200      A
3        123456        300      A
4        987654          0      A
6        987654        200      A
7        987654        300      A
8        654321          0      B
9        654321        100      B
10       654321        200      B
11       654321        300      B
```

Comment: I played around with this and it's an excellent answer and very easy to understand on my larger data set. I was able to get the expected output. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Creating a filter in one line was a challenging task.

```
import pandas as pd

# Conditions:

"""
if (df["Source"]=="A").count() > 0 then remove B, else, do nothing.

if (df["Source"]=="A").count() > 0 then remove B or multiple instances of B,
else, do nothing. Basically as long as there is an A, remove all Bs.

"""

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Part Number" : [123456, 123456, 123456, 123456, 987654, (987654), 987654, 987654, 654321, 654321, 654321, 654321],
    "Operation" : [000, 100, 200, 300, 000, (100), 200, 300, 000, 100, 200, 300],
    "Source" : ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", ("B"), "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
})

# Required output:

Required_output = pd.DataFrame({
    "Part Number" : [123456, 123456, 123456, 123456, 987654, 987654, 987654, 654321, 654321, 654321, 654321],
    "Operation" : [000, 100, 200, 300, 000, 200, 300, 000, 100, 200, 300],
    "Source" : ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
})
Solution = df.groupby("Part Number").apply(lambda x: x if 'A' in x['Source'].values else x[(x['Source'] != 'B') | (x['Operation'] != 100)]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(f"Raw Dataframe :\n{df}\n\nRequired output :\n{out}\n\nSolution :\n{Solution}")
```